# Orbeon Forms: working with xxf:dynamic

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm trying to add dynamic form with `xxf:dynamic` on Form Builder (ver. 4.9).

On "builder screen" I see input fields from dynamic instance, but when I want to test it by test button I don't see it at all.

Here is my code:

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
<xh:head>
    <xh:title>Untitled Form</xh:title>
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">

        <xf:instance id="dynamic-form">
            <xh:html>
                <xh:head>
                    <xh:title>Untitled Form</xh:title>
                    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">

        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                            <form>
                                <section-1>
                                    <control-1/>
                                    <control-3/>
                                </section-1>
                            </form>
                        </xf:instance>

                        <!-- Bindings -->
        <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds-nowy" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
                            <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                                <xf:bind id="control-1-bind" name="control-1" ref="control-1"/>
                                <xf:bind id="control-3-bind" ref="control-3" name="control-3"/>
                            </xf:bind>
                        </xf:bind>

                        <!-- Metadata -->



                        <!-- All form resources -->
        <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                            <resources>
                                <resource xml:lang="en">
                                    <section-1>
                                        <label>Untitled Section</label>
                                    </section-1>
                                    <control-1>
                                        <label>example 1</label>
                                        <hint/>
                                        <alert/>
                                    </control-1>
                                    <control-3>
                                        <label>example 2</label>
                                        <hint/>
                                    </control-3>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </xf:instance>

                        <!-- Utility instances for services -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                            <request/>
                        </xf:instance>

                        <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                            <response/>
                        </xf:instance>

                    </xf:model>
                </xh:head>
                <xh:body>
                    <fr:view>
                        <fr:body xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                                 xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                                 xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
                            <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                                <fr:grid>
                                    <xh:tr>
                                        <xh:td>
                                            <xf:input id="control-1-control" bind="control-1-bind">
                                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-1/label"/>
                                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-1/hint"/>
                                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                            </xf:input>
                                        </xh:td>
                                        <xh:td>
                                            <xf:input id="control-3-control" bind="control-3-bind">
                                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-3/label"/>
                                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-3/hint"/>

                                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                            </xf:input>
                                        </xh:td>
                                    </xh:tr>
                                </fr:grid>
                            </fr:section>
                        </fr:body>
                    </fr:view>
                </xh:body>
            </xh:html>

        </xf:instance>
        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <control-1/>
                </section-1>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Bindings -->
        <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                <xf:bind id="control-1-bind" name="control-1" ref="control-1"/>
            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>

        <!-- Metadata -->
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>test</application-name>
                <form-name>dynamic_site</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">Untitled Form</title>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
                <singleton>false</singleton>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Attachments -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- All form resources -->
        <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <section-1>
                        <label>Untitled Section</label>
                    </section-1>
                    <control-1>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                        <alert/>
                    </control-1>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Utility instances for services -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <request/>
        </xf:instance>

        <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xf:instance>

    </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <xxf:dynamic ref="instance('dynamic-form')"/>
        <fr:body xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                 xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
            <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="control-1-control" bind="control-1-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-1/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-1/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                        <xh:td/>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xh:body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the short answer is that `<xxf:dynamic>` is not documented  and should really be considered an internal feature for the use of Form Builder only at this point.